# Using "find" command with "-mtime" and "-exec rm -rf" Deletes More Files than Expected

Tags: find

I am testing with the following command line to delete older files on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
sudo find /media/Archive -type f -mtime +463 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Currently the /Archive folder has files from 2021 up to "today", separated by year i.e. /2021, /2022. Each filename includes the Julian day at the very end, e.g.

```
STN01.CH1.1 is Jan 1 2021
STN01.CH1.2 is Jan 2 2021
STN01.CH1.3 is Jan 3 2021
```

The Julian day corresponds to the timestamp of the file.

The test is to delete only file STN01.CH1.1 with timestamp Jan 1 2021.

The rationale for using "-mtime +463" is:

- Today is March 9, 2022, Julian day 99
- Jan 1 2021 is 365 days ago (in 2021) plus 99 days of 2022 = 464.
- Minus 1 day because the timestamp on the files is at 00:00 the next day as these are 24 hour files.

When I ran:

```
sudo find /media/Archive -type f -mtime +463 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

I got an unexpected result: it deleted days 1 to 331 of 2021 instead of only day 1 of 2021. Obviously my logic is faulty; if anyone tell me where I went wrong I would appreciate it.

Comment: Isn't today (March 9th) day 68 of 2022? (which doesn't help for your question, makes it worse.) Anyway, it seems to work for me: `find * -type f -mtime +415 -exec ls -l {} \; | grep " 2021 "` (I had to use 415 because I didn't have any files created earlier in January, 2021. The grep part is to filter out the huge number of previous years files.)

Comment: yeah, try `date -d "today - 463 days" +'%Y %j'` for example ... so your result is even curiouser (should cut off at 30 Nov 20**20**). Did you confirm the files' mtimes using `stat`?

Comment: @steeldriver 's point is very good because Nov 30, 2020 is day 335 of 2020. I wonder if you have an additional issue with which year, plus some rounding.

Comment: Duh! yes, March 9 = day 68, not 99. I have Julian Calendar chart and 99 is April 9. Sorry!

Comment: Why `-r` parameter to `rm` if you want only to delete files, not directories? Also, I prefer to use `-delete` instead of `-exec rm {} \;` - I think it's just safer in case of mistyping anything or strange things returned by `find` (plus avoids performance overhead due to spawning of additional program). I would be afraid that `rm` with `-r` parameter would indeed delete too much.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I made a mistake in the calculation of the days. This command line:

*sudo find /media/Archive/* -type f -mtime +433*

returned days 1 and 2 of 2021, as expected. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: The computer can calculate the number of days between today and Jan 1 2021: `echo "(( $(date +%s) - $(date -d 'Jan 1, 2021' +%s) )) / 86400" | bc`

Comment: @fuzzydrawings in this case it's probably simpler to make user of GNU find's `-newermt` predicate ex. `find /media/Archive/ -type f -not -newermt 2021-01-01`